# Xamarin: Can I add an image to Google Maps with bounds on iOS?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, mkmapview, mapkit

How do I add an image to google maps that has bounds? I have a rectangle image and would like to layer it on the map using its north-east and south-west points. Since the image is location based, I also want that image to re-size when the user zooms in and out.

Also posted on Xamarin forums: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92528/can-i-add-an-image-to-google-maps-with-bounds

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: @Dineshkumar, I haven't found a way to overlay an image to a section of a map. I only found examples of adding an image to annotations, for example, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/ios_maps_walkthrough/. In Android this can be done by using the Android.Gms.Maps.Model.GroundOverlay.PositionFromBounds() method.